# Cant get Nikons Raw SDK to load in Production environment

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, azure

I am using the Nikon Raw SDK and well, this might be a long short as not so many people uses this. But hoping there is some general advises to get here.

I have written a console application based on the SDK sample that reads an .Nef file and then with OpenCV it saves in any output format. This all works on my local machines.

Development Machine: windows 2012 R2 with Visual Studio 2010 (and 2013). Needed 2010 for the SDK.
Test Machine: Windows 8.1 with VS 2013.

Production Machine. Windows 2012 R2 (Windows Azure Cloud Service) with no Visual studio.

The application works on both development and test machine but not production, so I figured its something to do with not having VS installed. The application is in release mode. If i try to install c++ redistributable 2010 on the production machine it do tell me a newer version is already installed.

So I am out of ideas what it can be. Installing visual studio is not an option.

My biggest problem is that I dont have anything to go on, the code just give an error 8:

```
kNkfl_Code_Err_Unexpected                           = 0x0008,   //  Error: The reason may be bug.
```

I dont know if its any help to share the code because its alot (SDK sample from nikon, NkIL... files).

But I am hoping to get some in what could possible be installed on the dev/test machines that is not in production and I could try to install those.

I downloaded dependencywalker but I am not sure how to read the result.
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJTh5.png

and here is the development machine where the application do work.
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xjii.png

I also tried the profiler:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Started "NKIMGSDKSAMPLE.EXE" (process 0xCCC) at address 0x0000000140000000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "NTDLL.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF4280000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "KERNEL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "KERNELBASE.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF16D0000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF16D0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "KERNELBASE.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF16D0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "KERNELBASE.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF1DC0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "KERNEL32.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF1DC0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "KERNEL32.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
Injected "DEPENDS.DLL" at address 0x0000000052EA0000.
DllMain(0x0000000052EA0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "DEPENDS.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x0000000052EA0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "DEPENDS.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
Loaded "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052940000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "MSVCR100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052860000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "USER32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF2200000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "GDI32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF2800000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "ADVAPI32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF1D10000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "SHELL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF2950000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "COMCTL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF1830000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "OLE32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF1F00000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "MSVCP100.DLL" at address 0x00000000527C0000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "SHLWAPI.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF4220000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "MSIMG32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCE4110000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "MSVCRT.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF3E20000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "SECHOST.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF2380000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "RPCRT4.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF23E0000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "COMBASE.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF1B10000.  Successfully hooked module.
Entrypoint reached. All implicit modules have been loaded.
DllMain(0x0000000052860000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "MSVCR100.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x0000000052860000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "MSVCR100.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF2800000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "GDI32.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF2800000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "GDI32.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF2200000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "USER32.DLL" called.
Loaded "IMM32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF2520000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF40E0000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF3E20000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "MSVCRT.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF3E20000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "MSVCRT.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF40E0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "MSCTF.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF40E0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "MSCTF.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF2520000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "IMM32.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF2520000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "IMM32.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF2200000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "USER32.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF23E0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "RPCRT4.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF23E0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "RPCRT4.DLL" returned 4064190977 (0xF23EA201).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF1B10000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "COMBASE.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF1B10000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "COMBASE.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF4220000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "SHLWAPI.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF4220000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "SHLWAPI.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF2380000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "SECHOST.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF2380000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "SECHOST.DLL" returned 4064059649 (0xF23CA101).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF1D10000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "ADVAPI32.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF1D10000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "ADVAPI32.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF1830000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "COMCTL32.DLL" called.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "ProcessIdToSessionId") called from "COMCTL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF18333F4 and returned 0x00007FFCF1DC1734.
LoadLibraryW("imm32.dll") called from "COMCTL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF18334E9.
LoadLibraryW("imm32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF2520000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF2520000 [IMM32.DLL], "ImmCreateContext") called from "COMCTL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF1833513 and returned 0x00007FFCF252F314.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF2520000 [IMM32.DLL], "ImmDestroyContext") called from "COMCTL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF1833533 and returned 0x00007FFCF252F3A0.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF2520000 [IMM32.DLL], "ImmNotifyIME") called from "COMCTL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF1833553 and returned 0x00007FFCF2527408.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF2520000 [IMM32.DLL], "ImmAssociateContext") called from "COMCTL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF1833573 and returned 0x00007FFCF2522420.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF2520000 [IMM32.DLL], "ImmReleaseContext") called from "COMCTL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF1833593 and returned 0x00007FFCF25229D0.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF2520000 [IMM32.DLL], "ImmGetContext") called from "COMCTL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF18335B3 and returned 0x00007FFCF2522890.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF2520000 [IMM32.DLL], "ImmGetCompositionStringA") called from "COMCTL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF18335D3 and returned 0x00007FFCF25302A0.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF2520000 [IMM32.DLL], "ImmSetCompositionStringA") called from "COMCTL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF18335F3 and returned 0x00007FFCF253101C.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF2520000 [IMM32.DLL], "ImmGetCompositionStringW") called from "COMCTL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF1833613 and returned 0x00007FFCF253037C.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF2520000 [IMM32.DLL], "ImmSetCompositionStringW") called from "COMCTL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF1833633 and returned 0x00007FFCF253104C.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF2520000 [IMM32.DLL], "ImmSetCandidateWindow") called from "COMCTL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF1833653 and returned 0x00007FFCF2530D70.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF1830000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "COMCTL32.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCE4110000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "MSIMG32.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCE4110000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "MSIMG32.DLL" returned 4068551937 (0xF2812D01).
DllMain(0x0000000052940000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "MFC100.DLL" called.
LoadLibraryW("UxTheme.dll") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x000000005297559A.
Loaded "UXTHEME.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF0370000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF0370000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "UXTHEME.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF0370000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "UXTHEME.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
LoadLibraryW("UxTheme.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF0370000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF0370000 [UXTHEME.DLL], "DrawThemeParentBackground") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x00000000529A39C6 and returned 0x00007FFCF03749F0.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF0370000 [UXTHEME.DLL], "DrawThemeTextEx") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x00000000529A39E1 and returned 0x00007FFCF03B2CEC.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF0370000 [UXTHEME.DLL], "BufferedPaintInit") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x00000000529A39FC and returned 0x00007FFCF03B32A0.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF0370000 [UXTHEME.DLL], "BufferedPaintUnInit") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x00000000529A3A17 and returned 0x00007FFCF03B39E4.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF0370000 [UXTHEME.DLL], "BeginBufferedPaint") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x00000000529A3A32 and returned 0x00007FFCF03738D0.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF0370000 [UXTHEME.DLL], "EndBufferedPaint") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x00000000529A3A4D and returned 0x00007FFCF03739C0.
LoadLibraryW("D:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x000000005297559A.
Loaded "DWMAPI.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCEF990000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x00007FFCEF990000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "DWMAPI.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCEF990000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "DWMAPI.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
LoadLibraryW("D:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll") returned 0x00007FFCEF990000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCEF990000 [DWMAPI.DLL], "DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x00000000529A3AA8 and returned 0x00007FFCEF993158.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCEF990000 [DWMAPI.DLL], "DwmDefWindowProc") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x00000000529A3AC3 and returned 0x00007FFCEF992FD0.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCEF990000 [DWMAPI.DLL], "DwmIsCompositionEnabled") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x00000000529A3ADE and returned 0x00007FFCEF9912F0.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1830000 [COMCTL32.DLL], "DllGetVersion") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052AFEE6D and returned 0x00007FFCF18403B4.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.DLL") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x00000000529A612E.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.DLL") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "GetThreadPreferredUILanguages") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052AEFAE9 and returned 0x00007FFCF1E71440.
LoadLibraryExA("D:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MFC100ENU.DLL", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052AEFD2C.
Loaded "MFC100ENU.DLL" at address 0x00000000527B0000.  Successfully hooked module.
LoadLibraryExA("D:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MFC100ENU.DLL", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) returned 0x00000000527B0000.
DllMain(0x0000000052940000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "MFC100.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF2950000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "SHELL32.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF2950000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "SHELL32.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF1F00000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "OLE32.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF1F00000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "OLE32.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00000000527C0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "MSVCP100.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00000000527C0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x000000000013FB00) in "MSVCP100.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
LoadLibraryA("ADVAPI32.dll") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052BD75C0.
LoadLibraryA("ADVAPI32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1D10000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1D10000 [ADVAPI32.DLL], "RegOpenKeyExA") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052BD76BD and returned 0x00007FFCF1D113E0.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.DLL") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x00000000529A612E.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.DLL") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "GetThreadPreferredUILanguages") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052AEFAE9 and returned 0x00007FFCF1E71440.
LoadLibraryExA("d:\users\pksorensen\downloads\release\release\NKIMGSDKSAMPLEENU.dll", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052AEFD2C.
LoadLibraryExA("d:\users\pksorensen\downloads\release\release\NKIMGSDKSAMPLEENU.dll", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).
LoadLibraryExA("d:\users\pksorensen\downloads\release\release\NKIMGSDKSAMPLEENU.dll", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052AEFD2C.
LoadLibraryExA("d:\users\pksorensen\downloads\release\release\NKIMGSDKSAMPLEENU.dll", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).
LoadLibraryExA("d:\users\pksorensen\downloads\release\release\NKIMGSDKSAMPLEENU.dll", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052AEFD2C.
LoadLibraryExA("d:\users\pksorensen\downloads\release\release\NKIMGSDKSAMPLEENU.dll", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).
LoadLibraryExA("d:\users\pksorensen\downloads\release\release\NKIMGSDKSAMPLEENU.dll", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052AEFD2C.
LoadLibraryExA("d:\users\pksorensen\downloads\release\release\NKIMGSDKSAMPLEENU.dll", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).
LoadLibraryExA("d:\users\pksorensen\downloads\release\release\NKIMGSDKSAMPLEENU.dll", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052AEFD2C.
LoadLibraryExA("d:\users\pksorensen\downloads\release\release\NKIMGSDKSAMPLEENU.dll", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).
LoadLibraryExA("d:\users\pksorensen\downloads\release\release\NKIMGSDKSAMPLEENU.dll", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052AEFD2C.
LoadLibraryExA("d:\users\pksorensen\downloads\release\release\NKIMGSDKSAMPLEENU.dll", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).
LoadLibraryExA("d:\users\pksorensen\downloads\release\release\NKIMGSDKSAMPLELOC.dll", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052AEFD2C.
LoadLibraryExA("d:\users\pksorensen\downloads\release\release\NKIMGSDKSAMPLELOC.dll", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).
LoadLibraryA("ole32.dll") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052BD75C0.
LoadLibraryA("ole32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1F00000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1F00000 [OLE32.DLL], "OleInitialize") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052BD76BD and returned 0x00007FFCF1F2A460.
Loaded "KERNEL.APPCORE.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF0320000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF0320000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "KERNEL.APPCORE.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF0320000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "KERNEL.APPCORE.DLL" returned 1307905 (0x13F501).
Loaded "CRYPTBASE.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF1570000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "BCRYPTPRIMITIVES.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF1410000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF1410000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "BCRYPTPRIMITIVES.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF1410000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "BCRYPTPRIMITIVES.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF1570000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "CRYPTBASE.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF1570000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "CRYPTBASE.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1F00000 [OLE32.DLL], "CoRegisterMessageFilter") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052BD76BD and returned 0x00007FFCF1F30420.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1D10000 [ADVAPI32.DLL], "RegCreateKeyExA") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052BD76BD and returned 0x00007FFCF1D1E700.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1D10000 [ADVAPI32.DLL], "RegCloseKey") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052BD76BD and returned 0x00007FFCF1D111A0.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1D10000 [ADVAPI32.DLL], "RegQueryValueExA") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052BD76BD and returned 0x00007FFCF1D11250.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1830000 [COMCTL32.DLL], "InitCommonControlsEx") called from "MFC100.DLL" at address 0x0000000052BB2331 and returned 0x00007FFCF1834AF0.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF2200000 [USER32.DLL], "NotifyWinEvent") called from "COMCTL32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF183BB15 and returned 0x00007FFCF22020E0.
LoadLibraryExA("NkImgSDK.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) called from "NKIMGSDKSAMPLE.EXE" at address 0x000000014000D3A7.
Loaded "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180000000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "ZELKOVA7.DLL" at address 0x00000000005D0000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "WINMM.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCD5750000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "WS2_32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF3ED0000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "VERSION.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCE4380000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "WINMMBASE.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCD5700000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "NSI.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF3E00000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "CFGMGR32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF17E0000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "DEVOBJ.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF0510000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x00007FFCE4380000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "VERSION.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCE4380000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "VERSION.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00000000005D0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "ZELKOVA7.DLL" called.
LoadLibraryExW("d:\users\pksorensen\downloads\release\release\Zelkova7Lang.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) called from "ZELKOVA7.DLL" at address 0x00000000005EC2A2.
Mapped "ZELKOVA7LANG.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x0000000000620001.
LoadLibraryExW("d:\users\pksorensen\downloads\release\release\Zelkova7Lang.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned 0x0000000000620001.
DllMain(0x00000000005D0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "ZELKOVA7.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF17E0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "CFGMGR32.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF17E0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "CFGMGR32.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF0510000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "DEVOBJ.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF0510000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "DEVOBJ.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCD5700000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "WINMMBASE.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCD5700000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "WINMMBASE.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCD5750000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "WINMM.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCD5750000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "WINMM.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF3E00000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "NSI.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF3E00000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "NSI.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x00007FFCF3ED0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "WS2_32.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF3ED0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "WS2_32.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x0000000180000000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "NKIMGSDK.DLL" called.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093518.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "TryEnterCriticalSection") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093530 and returned 0x00007FFCF42CAFB0.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093518.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "TryEnterCriticalSection") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093530 and returned 0x00007FFCF42CAFB0.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "CreateHardLinkW") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x000000018071A1D1 and returned 0x00007FFCF1E9CF44.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "CreateSymbolicLinkW") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x000000018071A201 and returned 0x00007FFCF1E9D090.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093518.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "TryEnterCriticalSection") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093530 and returned 0x00007FFCF42CAFB0.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093518.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "TryEnterCriticalSection") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093530 and returned 0x00007FFCF42CAFB0.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093518.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "TryEnterCriticalSection") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093530 and returned 0x00007FFCF42CAFB0.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093518.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "TryEnterCriticalSection") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093530 and returned 0x00007FFCF42CAFB0.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093518.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "TryEnterCriticalSection") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093530 and returned 0x00007FFCF42CAFB0.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093518.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "TryEnterCriticalSection") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093530 and returned 0x00007FFCF42CAFB0.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093518.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "TryEnterCriticalSection") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093530 and returned 0x00007FFCF42CAFB0.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093518.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "TryEnterCriticalSection") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093530 and returned 0x00007FFCF42CAFB0.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093518.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "TryEnterCriticalSection") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093530 and returned 0x00007FFCF42CAFB0.
DllMain(0x0000000180000000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "NKIMGSDK.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
LoadLibraryExA("NkImgSDK.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned 0x0000000180000000.
GetProcAddress(0x0000000180000000 [NKIMGSDK.DLL], "Nkfl_Entry") called from "NKIMGSDKSAMPLE.EXE" at address 0x000000014000D3C3 and returned 0x0000000180014430.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093518.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "TryEnterCriticalSection") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093530 and returned 0x00007FFCF42CAFB0.
Loaded "SHCORE.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCEFD80000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x00007FFCEFD80000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "SHCORE.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCEFD80000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "SHCORE.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
Loaded "OLEAUT32.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF20E0000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF20E0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "OLEAUT32.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF20E0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "OLEAUT32.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
Loaded "CLBCATQ.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF2570000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF2570000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "CLBCATQ.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF2570000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "CLBCATQ.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
Loaded "PROPSYS.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCEC6A0000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x00007FFCEC6A0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "PROPSYS.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCEC6A0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "PROPSYS.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093518.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "TryEnterCriticalSection") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093530 and returned 0x00007FFCF42CAFB0.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093518.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "TryEnterCriticalSection") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093530 and returned 0x00007FFCF42CAFB0.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093518.
LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32.dll") returned 0x00007FFCF1DC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFCF1DC0000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "TryEnterCriticalSection") called from "NKIMGSDK.DLL" at address 0x0000000180093530 and returned 0x00007FFCF42CAFB0.
Loaded "SETUPAPI.DLL" at address 0x00007FFCF2620000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF2620000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "SETUPAPI.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x00007FFCF2620000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "SETUPAPI.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
```

Comment: I have tried installing VS10, VS13 and Desktop Experience on the production machine (same setup as my own 2012R2 server setup) but the application still wont load the SDK. Really not sure what differences there should be from my machine to the azure machine now.

Answer (score 0):

a few advises from https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/general-chat lead to

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx

and with process monitor I was able to filter my application out and log all actions it was doing. Loading dlls, accessing reg.keys ect.

This lead me to find that the color profiles was missing on the production server. These comes with Nikon SDK also.

When they got copyed over everything worked.